# How to export quality animated gifs in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, animation, gif

New to making animated gifs in photoshop (for loading designs). I know gifs aren't the highest quality format, but I've seen dribbble designs that look great, and they're gif format.

But when I export my animation the circle has jagged edges and the quality isn't great (the image, not the animation. I know it's not very smooth).

Is there a way to make it better?

http://screencast.com/t/fuuylIaGbp

Comment: I think that circle looks pretty good, to me.  I do notice that the animate (like you said) is not perfectly smooth, but I think the circle itself looks fine.

Comment: Why are you showing an example video of how it looks in photoshop, if the issue is in your exported gif?

Answer (score -1):

I was dealing with same issue.

Please make it 3x bigger and then set the width at 1x in HTML.

It would be much better!

Comment: It is **very poor** practice to use exceptionally large images and then reduce them via HTML.

Comment: Scott, its the only way to export quality GIFs. Have you ever sliced a PSD for Apple devices @2x, @3x?. Bigger size is much better than bad user experience (in this case pixelated edges). If you have better way to do it, then answer the question, but don't degrade other's, if you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: That is **not** how @2x/3x  images work. They are **not** resized via HTML tags.

Comment: @SOIA As long as file size isn't an issue theres no problem using oversized images and setting a smaller size in html.

Comment: File size is always an issue because bandwidth is always an issue, memory footprint on mobile devices is always an issue, computational overhead and its corresponding effect on battery life is always an issue. If you don’t know what you are doing and you for some reason don’t want to learn, then go basic: publish a basic 1:1 pixel ratio graphic at the actual size of the graphic.

Comment: The reason [GIF images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) are jagged on their edges is due to an indexed colour scheme. The transparent colour is exactly that - a single palette entry, there is no alpha channel.